# Failing to query OpenLibrary

Tags: json, api, restful-architecture

I want to compose a query to OpenLibrary's [RESTful API](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/books) that does the following:

1. filters the book list by the first five letters of the title
2. returns the book's title, author, publication date, description, and a link to the large thumbnail of the cover

So far this is all I've been able to compose with any success:

```
http://openlibrary.org/query.json?type=/type/edition&authors=/authors/OL1A&covers=&title=&publish_date=&description=
```

You can cut and paste into your browser to see the result, OpenLibrary doesn't require an API key.

My main obstacles seem to be:

1. I can't figure out how to filter the books by the first five letters of the title
2. I can't figure out how to turn the cover information into a link to the actual thumbnail

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The API does not allow you to a search the first 5 natives, but you it possible create a code to consume API and to apply the regex.

example:

- first five letters searched `Bhānu`
- the regex would look like this: `[Bhānu]` or `Bhānu`
- the regex would look like this: `"bhānumatīra deśa."`

link to regex example: https://regex101.com/r/cTVX1Z/4

Comment: Can you provide a link for regex? It's not a format I am familiar with.

Comment: The API does not look like it allows you to do a search on the first 5 letters.